# laravel seed rollback after seeding database

Tags: php, laravel, rollback, laravel-seeding

I have seeded my DB using `php artisan db::seed`. Is there a way to *rollback* what I have seeded into my DB?

I cannot seem to find any command like `php artisan db::seed rollback`.

Comment: Did you seed a new (empty) database? Or are you looking to undo some changes and restore the original database?

Comment: @ERullmann,  I am looking to undo the changes I have made using db::seed

Comment: That's a lot trickier if you don't have a backup. I don't think that artisan would offer a native service like that. You might want to check to see if there's a log about the SQL commands that were part of seed. Or if all your objects are timestamped with creation times you could delete everything created since you ran the command.

Comment: @Aaron I know this is old, but revering/rolling back seeds is absolute madness... If you are on production, you have to test everything (before) on another environment... If you are local (dev or similar), backup the DB all the time before testing new features or just test and wipe the DB with `php artisan migrate:fresh`... There is no real need of having a _rollback_ seeder... that means there is a poor implementation or usage of a seeder or similar... The solution is in other place, not in reverting a seeder.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Quite contrary I found such ability to be very handy (in development phase) when you need to make quick resets of your DB - I mean resetting ONLY things added through a seed and not anything else and not wiping whole DB.

Comment: @alex then why aren't you using unit testing ? You would have no need to do this then. I am just saying you are needing this because you are using something wrong or not using something that you should be using at all.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use Undo Seeder for Laravel.

When you install UndoSeeder, the following artisan commands are made available:

```
db:seed-undo    Undo seeds in the seeds directory.
db:seed-refresh Undo seeds run seeds again.
```

more [Undo-Seeder](https://github.com/killmenot/undo-seeder-laravel)

Answer (score 21):

> You may also seed your database using the migrate:refresh command, which will also rollback and re-run all of your migrations. This command is useful for completely re-building your database:

`php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`

[Running Seeders](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/seeding#running-seeders)

Comment: Is It ther a way run this command but  specifying a seeder class? ( like php artisan db:seed --class='CustomSeeder' =

Comment: @Berni yes, do `Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--class' => 'CustomSeeder']);` and `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;` on top.

Comment: @Berni or you could just comment out the seeder class that you want to avoid...

Answer (score 11):

If you want to wipe out certain table, then just TRUNCATE that table, and seed it again:

```
php artisan db:seed --class=UsersTableSeeder
```

No need for additional packages for such a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to go into your

> database/seeders

folder and manually delete the files you want to remove then run `php artisan migrate:fresh`.

Answer (score 0):

Open the database table with whichever platform you are using (phpMyAdmin / mySql-Workbench / a DB-editor plug-in etc.) and manually delete the seeded contents. Then you will be able to reseed the table using `php artisan db:seed`

Answer (score -2):

I was looking for something else like i have ran `php artisan db:seed` and after that I wanted to change something in `UserSeeder`, like changing an email address.

So if you want to change something in Seeder class and you have already run `db:seed` command.

Then first of all you have to add truncate function before any other code like if you have `UserSeeder` class then add below code in run function before seeding all `User` model:

```
User::truncate();
```

Then all you have to do is ***re-run*** the command.

```
php artisan db:seed
```

It will seed again all the classes as per your change and delete already seeded `Users` in Database, You can use this method for any model you want to truncate the table and re insert the records.