# How to undo last laravel db:seed?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-seeding

I have run a db:seed and in Laravel 5.4. Now I found that it was not to be run . So is there anyway in Laravel that we can undo the last db:seed and insert the table with previous data. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel seed rollback after seeding database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729769/laravel-seed-rollback-after-seeding-database)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to undo your seed(s) is by deleting them manually. With this sql command that should go pretty fast. As long as no data has been added after the seed you don't want to lose.

```
DELETE FROM {$table} ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT {$number_data_seeds}
```

Answer (score -1):

Database: Seeding is not migration, you can not rollback the last seed.

You can rollback all migrations and re-run all of your migrations and run seed, but you need to understand that when rolling back migrations, you lose all the data.

```
php artisan migrate: refresh --seed
```

Alternatively, you can look in the `database/seeds` folder and understand what changes you need to rollback and manually make changes to the database.

Please see the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/seeding
can you find that useful.

Comment: This will delete previous data too.