# When moving a Laravel repo to a new development environment, how can I get the tests running again?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I had developed a Laravel repo in WSL (Windows), and everything was fine.

Later, I bought a laptop with Ubuntu on it and wanted that to be my main development machine. So I downloaded my repo, copied over my various .env files, and set up the MySQL database with the appropriate schemas and users.

But my PHPUnit tests still wouldn't work.

And I was struggling to figure out from the Laravel docs what steps I'd missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These were the commands that I needed to run:

```
php artisan migrate --env=testing
php artisan db:seed --env=testing
```

Then `./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit tests/Feature/` worked fine.

P.S. `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed --env=testing` is also useful to [know about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48642749/470749).

Comment: Sounds like you could benefit from the `RefreshDatabase` testing trait, which would run the migrations for you if needed. Also, should tests really rely on externally run seeders?

Comment: @BrianThompson Thanks for those good points! I will look into those improvements.

Comment: @Ryan I am pretty sure you are a good developer, so remember always to read the documentation before attempting anything, as you are making use of 2 things: `--env` (this is not explained in the documentation, but run `php artisan`, you should see `--env` exists) in your commands and you lack the use of [`use RefreshDatabase`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test) trait.